# Is there a name for "inaccessible" concepts

Tags: concept

My question refers to three kinds of "inaccessible" concepts:

1. Those "humanly inaccessible" in the sense that we cannot conceive them as humans but that could be thought about with a proper brain structure (or with something other than a brain that enable thoughts) that is realizable within the limitations of our universe.
2. Those "weakly inaccessible", not strictly inaccessible, those that theoretically could be thought about by something within the constraints of our laws of physics but that will never be conceived no matter what by anything in the universe, even if even us humans if could think them.
3. Those "strongly inaccessible" in the sense that they couldn't be thought of no matter what due to fundamental limitations caused by the laws of physics, so that no arrangement of matter even theoretical, even involving much more matter than there actually is in the universe, couldn't produce thoughts about them. For instance, if any concept required having a "thinking structure" that is able to perform hypercomputation, it'd be out of reach for anything in our universe on a fundamental level.

Are there names for any of these three kinds? If there are, I would assume the names are different.

And if there are names and there are readings of interest related to the third kind, I'd be interested in reading that.

Comment: How can we conceive an "unconcivable" concept?

Comment: Of course we can't, but I don't pretend otherwise, we can still give this *kind* of concept a name even if we can't point out to specific ones, and we *could* probably reflect on the implications of whether or not such concepts exist. The last sentence in my post is just for my curiosity, I don't have a philosophy background.

Comment: It is more of a curiosity question as a whole for my own sake as I would like to try to think of ways to incorporate such elements in a science-fiction/fantasy setting. Hence why I'd like to be using the proper name for it (if there is one) and reading about it to learn subtleties I could have missed to avoid possible inconsistencies.

Comment: This sounds like how Chomsky views limits of biology. He identifies mysteries vs problems. Anything biological has limits of what it can conceive, although not necessarily what it can solve brutely without conceiving. Mysteries are those “concepts” forever beyond biological conceiving and problems are conceivable fully. Each species has its own mysteries and problems, and only some mysteries can be turned into problems by careful practice. Humans can interact with mysteries at surface level but never deep understanding. More powerful organisms than us could resolve our mysteries.

Comment: This indeed sounds like it's close. Am I right in saying that "humanly inaccessible" would refer to our mysteries as humans, that "weakly inaccessible" would refer to "any problem or mystery that are solvable but will never be solved in our universe" and that "strongly inaccessible" would refer to "mysteries that fundamentally cannot be just 'problems' for any theoretical being within the constraints of our laws of physics"?

Comment: I'd say the term you're looking for is *noumenal*. Noumenal thought processes are limits; Kant says, for example, that we don't know why space and time are the two forms of our intuition, or why the categories are the twelve forms of our discursion. "Something like space or time or something like the categories" is a description that can be satisfied only by information to which we don't have sufficient access.

Comment: I think Kant's noumenal is as close as you're going to get. Concepts, arguably, are constructed, and do not exist independent of cognition. [Constructivism in Math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)).

Comment: Reminds me of Donald Rumsfeld's known knowns, known unknowns, and unknown unknowns. Great philosopher, lousy SecDef. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns

Comment: "Noumenal" is a good suggestion, but that's really more about reality that we can't conceive (or have any information about) than it is about concepts that we can't conceive.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue against the idea of inaccessible concepts.

Concepts should be understood as abstractions that make modelling tractable, often by identifying symmetries, or otherwise dropping unnecessary information. Discussed here:
[As humans, do we require a total understanding of information to fully embody it as knowledge?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89990/as-humans-do-we-require-a-total-understanding-of-information-to-fully-embody-it/89991#89991)

The example of higher dimensions, can help us understand tools for conceiving things we can't directly experience: [Is it possible to visualize higher dimensional space?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/is-it-possible-to-visualize-higher-dimensional-space/51213#51213)

Then we have to look at whether the human brain is a limit. Modern science involves mega-projects, like the Standard Model of particle physics, or the Lambda-CDM model, resulting from the work of thousands of people, but learnable by one. Increasingly this involves augmenting human brains with computers, as well as through multi-generational networks of cooperation. Crucially, the increase in capacity of networks is far from linear, these impacts are cumulative and adapt to the problems they address.

That doesn't mean there are no limits on what can be conceptualised. Our brains can only hold a certain limit of symbols or representations in working memory, and they are crucial nodes. It may take deeper integration with AI like Neuralink, to go beyond that limit. But it's like a limit of pixels on the resolution of an image, it only impacts models with many layers of fine details which must be seen at once to be understood - currently only biological and social systems have that kind of intensive complexity, so we can reasonably expect biological systems to interact effectively with it.

Fundamentally, what is real we can interact with, what we can interact with we can conceptualise. Discussed here:
[Can knowledge exist that humans are incapable of understanding?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89169/can-knowledge-exist-that-humans-are-incapable-of-understanding/89178#89178)

Comment: Among all possible mathematical models that can be said to model something akin to a universe, I can not believe there isn't even a single one in which not only there exist things that can be described as sentient and in which, due to having laws of physics that enable much more complex behaviors (say, hypercomputation) for that universe's equivalent of matter, sentient beings are able to produce unique thoughts that couldn't be thought in our own no matter what. Whether or not such universes actually physically exist and are real does not matter to me: they mathematically could.

Comment: So even if there are limits on what can be conceptualised in our universe, I do believe there could be things beyond that limit, and even if such concepts had no meaning in ours, what matters to me is whether or not there is a theoretical mathematical model in which there can be arguably sentient beings which can make sense of it. In fact, them having no meaning in ours might probably even be a necessary condition to be unthinkable in our universe.

Comment: @Uro: Can we interact with those beings, & their universes? If not, ever, by any means, they are not part of our reality. If we can, we can come to share their understanding. But "If something about the mind of a knower means that is impossible, such as them being more advanced technologically than humans but uninterested in communicating, likely full communication may never be established." 'From the post Can knowledge exist that humans are incapable of understanding?' Linked above. This however, means not accessible, but not fundamentally *inaccessible*

Comment: I guess the true *limit*, would relate to the limits of assembling all the matter in our universe into a computation, using the then remaining entropy. But as discussed here, I don't think even that is a limit: 'What will humanity do IF and when technological progression ends?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/what-will-humanity-do-if-and-when-technological-progression-ends/89781#89781

Comment: We can't interact with them, since they are abstract mathematical objects. I think what I call "strongly inaccessible" is related to what you describe in your last comment, but goes beyond that since it lifts the restriction of having to work with with the "stuff" that actually is in our universe and refers to things that are mathematically thinkable but that couldn't be thought no matter what arrangement of *any* amount of matter given our laws of physics.

Comment: @Uro: As per dimensions example, interacting with a mental model counts. Rapidly cumulative things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers#Systematically_creating_ever-faster-increasing_sequences *can still be interacted with conceptually*. The distinction I make, is that I don't think unrealisable mathematics can meaningfully be called real, if abstractions or tokens of them can't interact with our world. They're literally metaphysical & not subject to any possible evidence. This is rooted in my view of mathematics, that it derives fundamentally from the world, not a platonic realm

Comment: I see for your first point, then if we count these types of interactions, we could be able to interact with *some* of them, but the interaction is ultimately very limited. For instance, we can understand conceptually hypercomputation, we can come up with theorems related to it and prove them, we can even determinate the result for very specific automata, but ultimately those results are very constrained, and a universe that does not support hypercomputation will never be able to extract everything there is to extract from them.

Comment: As for the reality of it, I don't know. Not coming from a philosophical background, even though I have opinions I am sure I miss subtleties in the meaning of the word "real" and might misuse some words, but I think we disagree on that. I view mathematics as something that would "exist" (in some abstract sense but exist nonetheless) even if there were no worlds to "witness" it. Not as some specific theory with this and that set of axioms, but as a self-consistent and self-defining logical "thing" that, on some level, contains truths about itself and other things that are within its reach.

Comment: @Uro: Then you hold a Mathematical Platonust view, a common & popular stance in modern philosophy: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics I would call that math-mysticism, the shadow of Pythagoras: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69573/about-wigners-view-on-the-relation-between-mathematics-and-physics/88534#88534 It basically contradicts the whole basis of progress in science, turn to evidence.